# how to create expendable layout on each node

Tags: android

im creating and application which have thre  nodes  (Description, Contents, Nutrition) like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3EUE.jpg    when user click any node it will expend and show another screen inside it how i will do that? i will see  there is expendable listview available but its show single list on each node like this example http://ranfeng0610.blog.163.com/blog/static/1857082842011727111359969/ is expend listview in each node i lie to expend layout on reach node al node show difrent layout User interface)  how i willl make screenlike this? help me please u have any idea????

```
           1、main.xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<!-- 禁用系统自带图标android:groupIndicator="@null" -->
<ExpandableListView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:groupIndicator="@null"
android:id="@+id/mExpandableListView"
/>
</LinearLayout>
 2、group.xml

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation = "horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView
android:layout_width = "25dip"
android:layout_height = "25dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:id="@+id/mImageView"
/>
 <TextView
android:id = "@+id/group_tv"
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft = "30px"
android:paddingBottom = "10px"
android:textSize = "26sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
3、child.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation = "horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
 android:layout_gravity = "center_vertical"
 android:id = "@+id/child_iv"
 android:layout_width = "70px"
 android:layout_height = "70px"
 android:paddingLeft = "30px"
 android:paddingTop = "2px"
 android:paddingBottom = "5px"
 android:src = "@drawable/icon"/>
 <TextView
  android:layout_gravity = "center_vertical"
 android:id = "@+id/child_tv"
 android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
 android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
 android:paddingLeft = "30px"
  android:paddingTop = "10px"
 android:paddingBottom = "5px"
 android:textSize = "30sp"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: u can make it without using expandable list-view..u have to just control visibility of your views..but if there r no of views which u want to expand then expandable list-view is preferable..!

Comment: but expendablelist view not support multiple screens is used single listview to all nodes

Comment: u know any example which show screens like this????

Comment: first tell me how many nodes r in your application?

Comment: 3 nodes and each show diffrent UI

Comment: i wan tto implement screen same like this screen http://imgur.com/TmJT6GI

Comment: k for that u do not require expandable listview.make 3 layouts(Relative or Linear) set click event on them and just control visibility of these layout...got it?

Comment: how?? any example????? little confuse about it

Comment: wait i m going to post my solution.

Comment: cant control visibility bcoz this sample screen is too  long http://imgur.com/TmJT6GI  used scroll view and user also see all three nodes and   just  expend each node at a time but visibility hide just hidden layout but is space will occur in screen

Comment: for that we need to put these layouts in scrollview..wait i m showing u example.

Comment: i m   still  waiting!!!!!!

Comment: ok im waiting  but please give me good solution which meet my requirment please!!!!!

Comment: where ru? i m still waiting

Comment: now i m here..wait for my answer..!

Comment: ok thnx ikiim waiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can make it without using expandable list-view..u have to just control visibility of your views.

**MainActivity**

```
boolean flag;
boolean flag2;
LinearLayout llContains;
LinearLayout llContents;
LinearLayout llContains2;
LinearLayout llContents2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     llContains = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llContains);
     llContents = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llContents);
     llContains2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llContains2);
     llContents2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llContents2);

     llContains.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(!flag)
            {
                llContents.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                flag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                llContents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                flag = false;
            }

        }
    });

    llContains2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(!flag2)
            {
                llContents2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                flag2 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                llContents2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                flag2 = false;
            }

        }
    });


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >

  <ScrollView 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  > 

<LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/llContains"  
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    >

  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Contains"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:padding="10dp"
       />

   <LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/llContents"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:weightSum="4"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:visibility="gone"
   >

   <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"
        >

   <ImageView 
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      />

    <TextView 

       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Cheese"
       />

   </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

    <ImageView 
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView 

       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Tomatos"
       />

    </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"
        >
     <ImageView 
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>

      <TextView 

       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Wheat"
       />

     </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"
        >
      <ImageView 
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>

       <TextView 

       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Salt"
       />

      </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>



 </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/llContains2"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    >

   </LinearLayout>

  <TextView 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Contains2"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:padding="10dp"
       />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/llContents2"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >

      <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"
        >

   <ImageView 
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      />

    <TextView 

       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Cheese"
       />

   </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

    <ImageView 
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView 

       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Tomatos"
       />

    </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"
        >
     <ImageView 
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>

      <TextView 

       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Wheat"
       />

     </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"
        >
      <ImageView 
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>

       <TextView 

       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Salt"
       />

        </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

if it helps then let me know.

Comment: @user2589245 run my code and click on contains.and click again on it.

Comment: The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

Comment: import android.view.View.OnClickListener; add this @user2589245

Comment: i guess is work now but im confuse about layout which layou i copy and paste three time for  3 buttons?help me  just paste this code for three time in xml .so many linearlayout im confuse   paste this single linearlayout  code for 3 time  please

Comment: this code is work thnx just copy and paste xml code for three buttons in confuse which linearlayout i copy and paste bcoz two layout are same id   android:id="@+id/llContents"     im confuse how to paste this code for three buttons

Comment: @user2589245 i have make code easier for u..please implement other things by yourself..and up vote my answer so that it will helpful to others.

Comment: not working check my code here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967492/how-to-add-one-more-linearlayout-in-my-code