# how to add one more linearlayout in my code?

Tags: android

how to expend linearlayout for three button i follow this tutorial which expend linearlayout for 1 button i just add 1 more button how but code is not run i follow this answer  [how to create expendable layout on each node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964039/how-to-create-expendable-layout-on-each-node) just simple add one more linearlayout  whats is worng inmy code help me please

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
 >

  <ScrollView 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  > 

 <LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/llContains"  
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 >

 <LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="3dp"
 android:background="#000000"
 >

</LinearLayout>

 <TextView 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="Contains"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:padding="10dp"
   />

  </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/llContents"  
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:weightSum="4"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:visibility="gone"
   >

    <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center"
    >

<ImageView 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  />

  <TextView 

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="Cheese"
   />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

 <ImageView 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <TextView 

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="Tomatos"
   />

 </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center"
    >
 <ImageView 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <TextView 

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="Wheat"
   />

 </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center"
    >
  <ImageView 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>

   <TextView 

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="Salt"
   />

   </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 > 

 <LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/llContains2"  
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 >

  <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="3dp"
   android:background="#000000"
   >

  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="Contains22"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:padding="10dp"
   />

 </LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/llContents2"  
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:weightSum="4"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:visibility="gone"
 >

   <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center"
    >

  <ImageView 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  />

   <TextView 

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="Cheese"
   />

 </LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

  <ImageView 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <TextView 

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="Tomatos"
   />

  </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center"
    >
 <ImageView 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <TextView 

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="Wheat"
   />

 </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center"
    >
  <ImageView 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>

   <TextView 

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="Salt"
   />

   </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

boolean flag;
LinearLayout llContains;
LinearLayout llContents;

LinearLayout llContains2;
LinearLayout llContents2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     llContains = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llContains);

     llContents = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llContents);


     llContains.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(!flag)
            {
                llContents.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                flag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                llContents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                flag = false;
            }

        }
    });


     llContains2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llContains2);

     llContents2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llContents2);


     llContains2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(!flag)
            {
                llContents2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                flag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                llContents2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                flag = false;
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: error occur  ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: i just want to add two more linearlayout in my code this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964039/how-to-create-expendable-layout-on-each-node  show one linearlayout  i want to show three linearlayout

Comment: wht is worng in my code?????????????????

Answer (score 1):

```
   <ScrollView 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width=""
        android:layout_height="">

    <Linearlayout ></LinearLayout>
    <Linearlayout ></LinearLayout>
    <Linearlayout ></LinearLayout>
    <Linearlayout ></LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: ScrollView can hold I child only.By making this change your scrollView will hold 1 child only ie relativeLayout. Relative layout can hold several layouts.